# Fallo construct() simpleXMLElement con XML, cURL, PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl

Estoy intentando crear una variable xml para enviar una solicitud con cURL, en el código que pongo a continuación tengo los siguientes errores:

- Al hacer el echo y el var_dump no se muestra nada, no hay error de sintaxis simplemente se queda una pagina en blanco, mi intencion es que se muestre lo que contiene el xml para asegurar que esta bien escrito.

En el log me indica que hay un error al construir la variable $xml_solicitud y $xml_respuesta

```
$xml_respuesta = new SimpleXMLElement($respuesta);
$xml_solicitud = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
```

Este es el código:

```
<?php
    
    $xmlstr ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <request type="schedule-new" timestamp="20170331140251">
    <merchantid>xxxxxxxxx</merchantid>
    <account>internet</account>
    <channel>ECOM</channel>
    <scheduleref>58de618b3279c</scheduleref>
    <transtype>auth</transtype>
    <schedule>4 *?</schedule>
    <numtimes>-1</numtimes>
    <payerref>'.htmlspecialchars($payerRef).'</payerref>
    <paymentmethod>'.htmlspecialchars($cardRef).'</paymentmethod>
    <amount currency="EUR">'.htmlspecialchars($precio).'</amount>
    <sha1hash>'.htmlspecialchars($hashFinal).'</sha1hash>
    </request>';
            
            
            /*---------------------------------- Enviamos y leemos solicitud con cURL -----------------------------*/
            
            ### Para este ejemplo la cadena $xmlstr tiene una cadena en formato xml
            //Iniciamos una sesion cURL
            $ch = curl_init();
            
            //Indicamos a donde deseamos enviar nuestro post
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://hpp.sandbox.addonpayments.com/pay" );
            
            //Indicamos lo que queremos enviar en nuestro post, en este caso un xml
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$xmlstr);
            
            //Configuramos los headers necesarios. En este caso es importante la definición de la longitud de los datos a enviar
    
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'Content-Type: application/xml',
      'Content-Length: ' . strlen( $xmlstr ),
      'Accept: application/xml',
      'Host: https://hpp.sandbox.addonpayments.com/pay'
      )
    );
            
            //Añadimos una opción más para poder almacenar la respuesta en una variable
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            
            //Ejecutamos el curl y almacenamos la respuesta en una variable
            $respuesta=curl_exec($ch);
    
    if ( false === $respuesta ) {
      echo "Error de cURL: " . curl_error( $ch ) . PHP_EOL;
    }
    
    $respuestaCode = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
    echo "Code HTTP: " . $respuestaCode . PHP_EOL;
    if ( 200 != $respuestaCode ) {
      echo 'Algo malio sal' . PHP_EOL;
    }
            
             //Cerramos nuesta sesión
            curl_close($ch);
            
            $xml_respuesta = new SimpleXMLElement($respuesta);
            $xml_solicitud = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
            
            echo $xml_solicitud->request->startdate;
            var_dump($xml_solicitud->request->startdate);
            
            if((string) $xml_respuesta->response[0]->result=="00"){
                Generamos mail de aviso
                $to      = "xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com"; // A quien se dirige
                $subject = 'Error en pago con recurrencia'; // Asunto del mail
                $message = '
            
                Error '.$xml_respuesta->response[0]->result.' con referencia de pagador '.$xml_solicitud->request[0]->payerref.' con fecha de inicio '.$xml_solicitud->request[0]->startdate.'.
            
                ';
            
                $headers = 'xxxxx@xxxxxxx.com' . "\r\n"; // Cabecera
                mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // Envio el correo
            }
        
        ?>
```

Comment: lo del correo puede ser que entre `' con fecha de inicio '` y `$xml_solicitud->request[0]->startdate` faltaría un `.` para concatenar, del resto te dejo pistas de cómo enviar un XML. fijate también si con las clases del api (composer/github) no es mas sencillo, lo mas cercano a un pago recurrente que vi está en uno de [los test de github](https://github.com/AddonPayments/php-sdk/blob/master/test/php/API/02%20-%20Almacenamiento%20de%20tarjeta/07%20-%20DCC/dcc.php#L34)

Comment: Te recomiendo que instales XDebug o alguno similar (en lugar de usar var_dump). Es mucho más claro y simple de debuggear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edición**

El error del constructor xml es porque estas intentando crear un xml a partir de un html no del todo correcto ( la respuesta err 400 que se ve en el log ), el problema está mucho antes: en el formato del xml, los datos que lo componen, o las cabeceras enviadas.

Quitando la cabecera 'host' el code es 200 y devuelve un "xml" correcto ( aunque como los datos del xml enviado son cualquiera la respuesta es en sí un error )

```php
// Configuramos los headers necesarios.
// En este caso es importante la definición de la longitud de los datos a enviar
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-Type: application/xml',
  'Content-Length: ' . strlen( $xmlstr ),
  'Accept: application/xml',
//  'Host: https://hpp.sandbox.addonpayments.com/pay'
  )
);
```

Da como respuesta:

```
> POST /pay HTTP/1.1
Host: hpp.sandbox.addonpayments.com
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 534
Accept: application/xml

* upload completely sent off: 534 out of 534 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200
< Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:d078d25d-db86-42cf-88e7-0d8f9ef12ee7
< X-CONTENT-TYPE-OPTIONS: nosniff
< X-Application-Context: HPPAzure:Azure:8080
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=C2CFF2C5AD9BB68172A2D7A9C1EEEE9A; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Content-Type: text/html
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Mon, 16 Nov 2020 20:08:00 GMT
< Server: Apache Tomcat
<
* Connection #0 to host hpp.sandbox.addonpayments.com left intact
Code HTTP: 200
string(482) "<!DOCTYPE html>

<html><head><base href="https://hpp.sandbox.addonpayments.com:443/merchants/null/null/" />
                <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
                <title>Error</title>
        <title>HPP</title></head>
<body>

                <h1 id="error_code">320</h1>
                <h2 id="error_message">An error has occurred processing your request. Please contact the merchant whose goods or services you are purchasing quoting the following error number: 61,338</h2>


</body>
</html>"
NULL
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'result' of non-object in /home/alejandro/Code/testing/curlXML/testXML.php on line 105
```

Cambiando los headers de content type y accpt también responde igual

```php
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
  'Content-Length: ' . strlen( $xmlstr ),
  'Accept: application/json',
//  'Host: https://hpp.sandbox.addonpayments.com/pay'
  )
);
```

El html devuelto por una respuesta con código 200 es considerado un xml válido, aunque al no haber validación, de por ejemplo el elemento `id="error_code"` que en este caso vale `320`, el código que intenta acceder a la propiedad `result` da error.

---

**Respuesta original**

Varias cosas pueden ser:

- el heredoc y las tabulaciones/espacios ( el formateo de código puede romperlo )
- caracteres especiales dentro del xml que lo rompen
- el `Content-Type` usado para enviar los datos
- el `Content-Type` declarado para recibir los datos

Propuestas:

- heredoc y caracteres especiales

Usamos un string con comillas simples y la función [`htmlspecialchars`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars.php) para tener un XML válido. ( también podes armarlo con [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php) o [`XMLWriter`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.xmlwriter.php) )

```php
<?php
// datos de ejemplo masomenos ( faltaría calcular los sha1 para que pase )
// https://desarrolladores.addonpayments.com/#!/api/scheduler/schedule-new
$timestamp = time();
$merchantID ='MerchantID';
$scheduleRef = '58de618b3279c';
$payerRef = '03e28f0e-4cf0-492e-80bd-20ec318e9334';
$cardRef = '3c4af936-3732-483e-a393-f558bec2fb2a';
$precio = 1001;

// SHA-1a = "timestamp.merchantid.scheduleref.amount.currency.payerref.schedule"
// SHA-1b = SHA-1a . secret
$hashFinal = '6616a0949b15de433f25cfc4cc5ec5f6f9518e69';

$xmlstr = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request type="schedule-new" timestamp="' . htmlspecialchars( $timestamp ) . '">
<merchantid>' . htmlspecialchars( $merchantID ) . '</merchantid>
<account>internet</account>
<channel>ECOM</channel>
<scheduleref>' . htmlspecialchars( $scheduleRef ) . '</scheduleref>
<transtype>auth</transtype>
<schedule>4 *?</schedule>
<numtimes>-1</numtimes>
<payerref>' . htmlspecialchars( $payerRef ) . '</payerref>
<paymentmethod>' . htmlspecialchars( $cardRef ) . '</paymentmethod>
<amount currency="EUR">' . htmlspecialchars( $precio ) . '</amount>
<sha1hash>' . htmlspecialchars( $hashFinal ) . '</sha1hash>
</request>';
```

- el `Content-Type` usado para enviar los datos

Al estar enviando un XML hay que especificar una cabecera con el tipo de contenido:  `Content-Type:application/xml` o alternativamente como `Content-Type:text/xml;charset=UTF-8` ( se incluye el charset de acuerdo a [RFC7303](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7303) ).

- el `Content-Type` declarado para recibir los datos

Si la respuesta la querés en XML también hay que especificarlo con la cabecera `Accept:application/xml`

```php
// estamos enviando un XML
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlstr );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-Type: application/xml',
  'Content-Length: ' . strlen( $xmlstr ),
  'Accept: application/xml',
  'Host: https://hpp.sandbox.addonpayments.com/pay'
  )
);
```

- Para ver detalles de la conexión podes activar el modo parlanchín de curl

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

Dicho todo esto, en la prueba por consola ( seguramente debido a que los datos son cualquiera ) da como respuesta un error 400.

```
$ php testXML.php
*   Trying 51.145.190.183:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to hpp.sandbox.addonpayments.com (51.145.190.183) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: businessCategory=Private Organization; jurisdictionC=ES; jurisdictionST=Madrid; serialNumber=B65466997; C=ES; L=Barcelona; O=Comercia Global Payments, Entidad de Pago SL; OU=eCommerce; CN=hpp.sandbox.addonpayments.com
*  start date: Jul 16 00:00:00 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 20 12:00:00 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "hpp.sandbox.addonpayments.com" matched cert's "hpp.sandbox.addonpayments.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=Thawte EV RSA CA 2018
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /pay HTTP/1.1
Host: https://hpp.sandbox.addonpayments.com/pay
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 534
Accept: application/xml

* upload completely sent off: 534 out of 534 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 400
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Language: en
< Content-Length: 755
< Date: Sat, 14 Nov 2020 23:24:28 GMT
< Connection: close
< Server: Apache Tomcat
<
* Closing connection 0
Code HTTP: 400
Algo malio sal
string(755) "<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</title><style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p><p><b>Description</b> The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat</h3></body></html>"
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name in /home/alejandro/Code/testing/curlXML/testXML.php on line 73
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): <!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</tit in /home/alejandro/Code/testing/curlXML/testXML.php on line 73
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct():  ^ in /home/alejandro/Code/testing/curlXML/testXML.php on line 73
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in /home/alejandro/Code/testing/curlXML/testXML.php on line 73
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): <!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</tit in /home/alejandro/Code/testing/curlXML/testXML.php on line 73
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct():  ^ in /home/alejandro/Code/testing/curlXML/testXML.php on line 73
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in /home/alejandro/Code/testing/curlXML/testXML.php:73
Stack trace:
#0 /home/alejandro/Code/testing/curlXML/testXML.php(73): SimpleXMLElement->__construct()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/alejandro/Code/testing/curlXML/testXML.php on line 73
```

El servidor no respeta el accept y responde con un html, así que ahí habrá que testear si la respuesta trajo un error code para no parsear un html ( o false si falló el curl ) como xml. Algo así:

```php
//Ejecutamos el curl y almacenamos la respuesta en una variable
$respuesta = curl_exec( $ch );

if ( false === $respuesta ) {
  echo "Error de cURL: " . curl_error( $ch ) . PHP_EOL;
}

$respuestaCode = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
echo "Code HTTP: " . $respuestaCode . PHP_EOL;
if ( 200 != $respuestaCode ) {
  echo 'Algo malio sal' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: He quitado todos los espacios y añadido todas las recomendaciones que me has puesto pero el problema persiste, sale el error 400 y sigue indicandome error en el constructor simpleXMLelement(); Actualizo mi pregunta para que veas el código actualizado

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta me ha ayudado mucho, pero sigo sin entender porque al enviar la solicitud me sale el error 200, yo en principio pongo datos validos y lo envio a la url correcta.

Comment: [response code `200`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200) no es un error de por sí, el error ( en mi ejemplo ) está dentro de la respuesta es un 320 que puede significar que alguno de los valores que yo envío no están correctos, en [el manual online no dice mucho tampoco](https://desarrolladores.addonpayments.com/#!/technical-resources/messages) vas a tener que contactar al servicio técnico a ver que ondas

Comment: Perfecto, pues hablaré con el banco a ver, un detalle mas, para poder ver el contenido de mi xml como lo podria mostrar, si hago var_dump o echo me sale null, es para poder comprobar campos y enviar datos por el correo.

Comment: el que envias lo ves con `var_dump( $xmlstr );`  lo que recibís lo ves con `var_dump( $respuesta, $respuestaCode );` justo después del `curl_close` y antes de intentar crear el simpleXML

Answer (score 1):

Atención: este es el error más común al usar la [sintaxis heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) para delimitar un string.

El cierre **no puede estar tabulado**. Tiene que estar al inicio de la línea!

[image: Se señala el espacio antes del cierre]

Citando a la ayuda de PHP:

> Es muy importante señalar que la línea con el identificador de cierre no debe contener ningún otro carácter, excepto un punto y coma (;). Esto, en especial, significa que el identificador no debe estar sangrado, y que no debe existir ningún espacio ni tabulación antes o después del punto y coma. Es muy importante observar que el primer carácter antes del identificador de cierre debe ser un salto de línea definido por el sistema operativo local. Este es \n en los sistemas UNIX, incluyendo Mac OS X. Al delimitador de cierre le ha de seguir tambíen una nueva línea.

Comment: He quitado todos los espacios y el problema persiste, sigue indicandome error en el constructor simpleXMLelement();